crop document within an image
enter image description here
enter image description here
Hello to everyone. I am working on a project as a student. I have many such documents and my task in the project is to write a function that reads the texts in these documents. At first I thought of cropping the blue borders and turning these images into a rectangular image, but I failed. can you help me? Since I had multiple images and most of them showed different tones of blue due to the lighting angle, I had a hard time finding the optimum settings.
I try contour blue but I can't because all blues have on different tones. so, I need how can I overcome this problem?
import cv2
import numpy as np

def find_blue_contour(image):
    # Convert the image to HSV color space
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    
    # Define the blue color range in HSV
    lower_blue = np.array([110, 50, 50])
    upper_blue = np.array([130, 255, 255])
    
    # Create a mask for the blue color
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)
    cv2.imshow("mask",mask)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    # Find contours in the mask
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    
    # If no contours are found, return None
    if not contours:
        return None
    
    # Find the largest contour
    largest_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
    
    return largest_contour

def crop_image_around_contour(image, contour):
    # Get the bounding rectangle of the contour
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    
    # Crop the image around the bounding rectangle
    cropped_image = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    
    return cropped_image

# Image path
image_path = 'dene1.JPeG'

# Load the image
image = cv2.imread(image_path)

if image is None:
    print(f"Error: Could not load image {image_path}.")
    exit()

# Find the blue contour
blue_contour = find_blue_contour(image)

if blue_contour is None:
    print("Error: Could not find blue contour.")
    exit()

# Crop the image around the blue contour
cropped_image = crop_image_around_contour(image, blue_contour)

# Display the original and cropped images
cv2.imshow("Original Image", image)
cv2.imshow("Cropped Image", cropped_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


In both of your example images the blue areas go nearly to the image border. What would be the purpose of getting the bounding rectangle of their contours?

Yes, it looked like that in these examples, but it is not normally like that. There is usually space on all sides.

second page is warped, not flat. that's an issue.

Please add a reasonable input image and a manual sketch of what you would like to get as result in that case!

If you can take photos of the pages without bending them (warping the image), and if the blue borders are completely continious in the image the problem becomes trivial.
Apply blue color filtering > Find biggest external contour > Find min area bounding rectrangle > Apply warp perspective. If you can share example images as described i can share an example code.
